# Integer values with character appeneded to it

Tags: r

My dataset contains 5 columns,column 1 is `RegionID`, whose class is factor class and mode is integer. but few numbers in the `RegionID` column has characters appended to it like (`670HH, 670XX, XX457`) etc..
My task is to search for those numbers and replace those characters with `0`.

`grep()` and `sub()` can be used only for strings and character vectors. so I tried to converting this column into character vector. But as I convert it into character vector its actual values are changing.

Could you please suggest me an appropriate solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you have, realize with an an example of data it would be better, if you could paste how it look now your data it would be easier. Just type `head(dataset)` and copy it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the column to a character using the `as.character()`.  Then you can use `sub()` to change the letters to 0's.  Then you can convert to numeric with `as.numeric()`, but note that the leading 0's will no longer appear.

Answer (score 0):

`gsub(...)` does work on factors.

```
str  <- c("12345", "670HH", "670XX", "XX457")
fstr <- facor(str)
fstr
# [1] 12345 670HH 670XX XX457
# Levels: 12345 670HH 670XX XX457

gsub('[A-Z]',"0",fstr)
# [1] "12345" "67000" "67000" "00457"
```

As pointed out already, you could convert these to numeric using `as.numeric(...)`, but then you would loose the leading zeros.